# How does one retrieve the hashlist of a collection in devnet?

Tags: devnet

Tools like MagicEden's [mintlist-tool](https://magiceden.io/mintlist-tool) only work on mainnet.
How can I acquire a hashlist of a collection on devnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CLI Based Tool Metaboss to get the HashList. Go through the installation Guide and use the command [here](https://metaboss.rs/snapshot.html#snapshot-mints)